# Формат "дд.мм.гггг года рождения"

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Обычно справки с места работы начинаются с таких слов:

> Справка выдана Иванову Ивану Ивановичу(,) 01.01.1980 ***года рождения(,)*** в том...

Меня смущают слова *"года рождения":* вроде они должны относиться ко всей дате, а не только к году. Но, если это и неправильно, я не могу найти хорошей замены этому. Вот по-английски всё просто: лучше всего написать "born on" и выделить запятыми. *А как можно это по-русски получше сформулировать?*

Запятые я поставил в скобки, потому что видел, что иногда это обособляют. Но мне кажется, что если уж так формулировать, то обособление не нужно. Я прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Не надо пытаться переформулировать.

Реальность в том, что все так пишут, но никто толком не понимает, почему "года рождения" (или г. р.) всегда и всюду присутствует вопреки смыслу, хотя вроде как речь о дате, а не о годе.

Первое, что могу сказать, бороться бесполезно, фактически это уже узаконенный оборот.

Второе. Откуда пошло. Видимо, из тех времен, когда дата без года не воспринималась. Наши предки в записи типа "Первое января" видели не просто некую календарную дату, а именно число и месяц, привязанную к году (обычно - текущему или известному по контексту, но именно к году).

Это потом у нас появилось "год рождения" (не понятие, а термин) в отрыве от даты. А до этого и число, и месяц были привязаны году. Так что история длинная и имеет под собой некоторые основания. Впрочем, сама форма такой записи несет явный отпечаток канцелярско-бюрократического строя советской эпохи. При царе-батюшке были другие обороты для выражения подобных фактов.

Повторюсь, ломать сейчас что-либо - бессмысленно.

Что касается запятых, то мне они кажутся лишними, хотя понимаю основания для их использования. Просто эти основания не настолько императивны, чтобы обособлять даже такую конструкцию, не нарушающую плавность речи.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший ответ!) Ну и хорошо, значит, теперь буду к этому спокойно относиться.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *А правда, почему неудивительно-то?* - сюда гляньте. http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200403709 Просто некоторые авторы бездумно относят к канцеляриту **любой** канцелярский оборот. Поэтому неудивительно, что встречаются такие "недоудивленные".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *И сюда еще гляньте, не поленитесь.*  http://gramma.ru/ARR ==== Вопрос 826: Как правильно написать: "справка выдана О том" или "В том, что"? Ответ: В тексте справки используется устойчивое сочетание: справка выдана (дана) в том, что…

Comment: @behemothus правильно сделали, что восстановили. А у вас торчит самомнение? Вот фото словарных статей: http://vfl.ru/fotos/86afcedf13701493.html, http://vfl.ru/fotos/2422b2b913701504.html. Одна новая (2016), другая старая. Поищите там *в том, что*. Канцеляритом называется неуместно употребленный канцеляризм. Я говорил о канцелярите. Что не так? Правда, в *справке в том, что* не стилистическая, а грамматическая ошибка. Хотя некоторые, как видно, считают это устоявшимся оборотом. Стилистическая - это канцелярит как раз. Вот и все, собственно. *За* какие вам еще *слова ответить*?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43824/discussion-between-behemothus-and-aer).

Comment: *Реальность в том, что никто не понимает, почему "года рождения" (г. р.) всегда и всюду присутствует вопреки смыслу.* Дорогой @behemothus, это вы не понимаете. Не надо говорить за всех. Уберите это "года рождения" ("г.р.") – и получите: "Ивану Ивановичу, 01.01.1980, в том, что он..." Прояснилось немного?

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, употребление слов *года рождения* после даты, записанной в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, как минимум нелогично. Хорошей альтернативой, на мой взгляд, было бы что-то такое: *Иванову Ивану Ивановичу (дата рождения - 01.01.1980)*. Запятые не нужны: это определение.

Странно, что ваше внимание не привлекает оборот "справка **в том, *что***". Справка может быть о ком-чем, о том, как (что, где, когда...). Но никак не *в том*.

Несмотря на существующее мнение, что *справка в том, что* - устоявшийся оборот (см. ссылки в комментариях Behemothus), стоит признать синтаксическую ошибку в управлении: http://ask.fm/russian/answer/138067660092, http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=283260, http://goo.gl/a7lrxF (http://za-rya.ru/spravka/; имена и время скрыты), http://goo.gl/x0Qom3 (Большой универсальный словарь русского языка; АСТ-Пресс, 2016), http://goo.gl/a0PjRV (Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка; Русский язык, 1983), http://goo.gl/Xhb5hS (Комплексный словарь русского языка под редакцией А. Н. Тихонова; Дрофа, 2009). *(Будет дополняться.)*

Comment: *"справка в том, что"* - справка **дана** [для удостоверения] в том, что... Вот вы клянете канцелярские обороты, а логику их возникновения не понимаете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А правда, почему неудивительно-то?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *А правда, почему неудивительно-то?* - сюда гляньте.  http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200403709 Просто некоторые авторы бездумно относят к канцеляриту **любой** канцелярский оборот. Поэтому неудивительно, что встречаются такие "недоудивленные".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой И сюда еще гляньте, не поленитесь. http://gramma.ru/ARR/  ====  Вопрос 826:    Как правильно написать: "справка выдана О том" или "В том, что"?
Ответ:   В тексте справки используется устойчивое сочетание: справка выдана (дана) в том, что…

Comment: @Аer, а к кому вы обращаетесь, когда спрашиваете "Почему неудивительно"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Тут нет обращения. Это риторическая фигура.