# Выделять ли запятыми слова "1 января 2014 года рождения"?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Установлена опека над Ивановой Марией Ивановной, 1 января 2014 года рождения, и Ивановым Александром Ивновичем, 15 марта 2016 года рождения.

Comment: А что, в ведомствах практикуется подобная фразеология - "1 января 2014 года рождения"? "Год рождения" - вроде как неделимое сочетание, относимое только к году, так что в результате число и месяц повисают в воздухе (не говорят ведь "1 января рождения"). Можно написать иначе: "_... над Ивановой Марией Ивановной (дата рождения: 1 января 2014 года ) и Ивановым Александром Ивновичем (дата рождения: 15 марта 2016 года)_".*

Comment: Подобный вопрос обсуждался здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426328/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b4-%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b3-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f.  Во-первых, это принятая бюрократическая практика, во вторых, можно оправдаться тем, что имеется в виду "рождения 1 января 2014 года"

Comment: Если имеется в виду "исправительный" порядок слов, то "оправданием" могло бы стать только его применение :)

Answer (score 1):

Запятые поставлены правильно. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Победитель 7 загона ― Антонина Ильинична Вяземская, 1932 года рождения. [коллективный. Форум: Горный двухподвесочный (2010)]
>
> В конце концов я узнал, что Иванько Сергей Сергеевич, 1925 года рождения: а) родственник бывшего председателя КГБ Семичастного; б) ближайший друг бывшего представителя СССР в Организации Объединённых Наций, ныне главного редактора журнала "Иностранная литература" и секретаря Союза писателей СССР Николая Т. Федоренко; в) сам по себе тоже большая шишка [Владимир Войнович. Иванькиада, или рассказ о вселении писателя Войновича в новую квартиру (1976)]
>
> И из полицейского ведомства, с которым он так сжился, карточку его и душу его передали воинскому начальнику, а тот, ничего не смысля ни в социал-демократах, ни в членах ЦК, призвал Иосифа Джугашвили, 1879 года рождения, ранее воинской повинности не отбывавшего, ― в русскую императорскую армию рядовым. [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 1-25 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

Истины ради, надо сказать, что справочная служба сайта Грамота в некоторых случаях отвечает, что запятые не нужны, в другом ответе пишет, что они опциональны (можно выделить дату рождения как уточнение). Мое мнение: в реальных документах дата рождения выделяется запятыми.

> Вопрос № 284251
>   Добрый день! Ставится ли запятая после ФИО, перед датой рождения? /Иванов Петр Иванович, 23.05.1999 г.р. или Иванов Петр Иванович 23.05.1999 г.р.?/
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Фраза построена неудачно. Возможные варианты: Иванов Петр Иванович, родившийся 23.05.1999; Иванов Петр Иванович, 1999 г. р.  Однако следует признать, что **формулировка такой-то, 01.01.1990 года рождения... устоялась в канцелярской речи и вошла во многие шаблоны и образцы.** В ней возможны варианты пунктуации: либо поставить обе запятые (выделить дату рождения как уточнение), либо убрать оба знака.
>
> Вопрос № 287497
>   подскажите пожалуйста как правильно расставить запятые в предложении"направляется уголовное дело в отношении Иванова Ивана Ивановича 5 мая 1950 года рождения уроженца г. Нижнего Новгорода"
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Корректная пунктуация: Направляется уголовное дело в отношении Иванова Ивана Ивановича **5 мая 1950 года рождения**, уроженца г. Нижнего Новгорода.

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите, нужны ли на месте вопросительных знаков запятые? В их семье было трое детей: дочь Людмила(?) 1925 года рождения, сын Михаил(?) 1928 года рождения, сын Алексей(?) 1930 года рождения.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Запятые нужны.

В справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя сказано следующее. Обычно обособляются несогласованные определения, дополняющие или уточняющие представление о лице либо предмете, который сам по себе (без определения) достаточно конкретен, уже известен. В этой роли выступают имена собственные (они выделяют лицо-предмет из ряда подобных), названия лиц по степени родства.